# Compare two observations and keep the higher Vale

Tags: r, dataframe, max, data-manipulation

I have a DF that looks like this;

```
ID      Station   Date       Value
111-001 Place1   2022-05-01  39.1
111-002 Place2   2022-05-01  0.01
222-001 Place1   2022-05-02  8.5
222-002 Place2   2022-05-02  40.3
```

I'd like to compare the similar IDs and keep the higher of the two. How is the best method to achieve this? I prefer using packages to base and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `susbtr` to `group_by` the 3 first numbers of ID, then use `max`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  group_by(gp = substr(ID, 1, 3)) %>% 
  mutate(max = max(Value))

# A tibble: 4 × 6
# Groups:   gp [2]
  ID      Station Date       Value gp      max
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1 111-001 Place1  2022-05-01 39.1  111    39.1
2 111-002 Place2  2022-05-01  0.01 111    39.1
3 222-001 Place1  2022-05-02  8.5  222    40.3
4 222-002 Place2  2022-05-02 40.3  222    40.3
```

---

In base R, use `ave`:

```r
with(dat, ave(Value, substr(ID, 1, 3), FUN = max))
#[1] 39.1 39.1 40.3 40.3
```

Comment: That works for finding which is higher, but I actually wanted to drop the row that is less.

Answer (score 3):

Using `base R`

```
transform(dat, Max = ave(Value, trimws(ID, whitespace = "-\\d+"), FUN = max))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `aggregate()` in baseR. Change `ID` to `factor`

```
df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
# and do 
aggregate(.~ID, df, FUN = max)
```

gives

```
       ID Value
1 111-001  39.1
2 111-002  40.3
```

data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("111-001", "111-002", "111-001", "111-002"), 
                 Value = c(39.1, 0.01, 8.5, 40.3))
```

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[which.max(Value)], by=ID]
```

Output:

```
        ID Station       Date Value
1: 111-001  Place1 2022-05-01  39.1
2: 111-002  Place2 2022-05-02  40.3
```

#### Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("111-001", "111-002", "111-001", "111-002"),
                 Station = c("Place1", "Place2", "Place1", "Place2"),
                 Date = c("2022-05-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-05-02", "2022-05-02"),
                 Value = c(39.1, 0.01, 8.5, 40.3))
```